# Merging windows of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Say I have two windows of Google Chrome, each with multiple tabs. Is there a way to merge the two windows (other than manually dragging the tabs one at a time from one window to the other)?

Comment: You may want to revisit the accepted answer - this is now built-in in Chrome (per @Seph's answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [**Windows To Tabs**](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/imppdbokooankkibjmcfgdlemfpiobie) extension for Chrome will do the trick.

[image]

You simply hit a button in Chrome and all tabs from any open windows are merged into one window.

[image]

In fact, there are loads of extensions out there, like [**JoinTabs**](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/binjiceocgbfooocmheaenmmcominbpe) which gives you more control over what windows are merged into what other windows.

Comment: See my answer which notes that extensions are no longer needed to do this same function (since Chrome version 24)

Comment: The problem with using extensions for tiny items like this, is that each extension uses another 10-20MB of RAM. Chrome is so memory hogging when it comes to extensions. :(

Comment: The extension link 404s now, and likely no longer exists.

Answer (score 94):

This functionality now exists in Chrome and has since version 24 or earlier. - So no need for extensions (any more)

Left-click the first tab in the window you want to merge, then hold the shift key and left-click the right most tab. All of the selected tabs for the current window can now be dragged and dropped as as group on another Chrome window.

Comment: This does not work as of Chrome 52

Comment: @WoJ I'm using Chrome 52.0.2743.82 m and it does still work exactly as I described above.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting then - in my case that pressing shift does not change anything - it just selects the tab as without the shift (there is no selection)

Comment: Just to corroborate this does work. Click + Shift Click for a contiguous set or Click + Ctrl Click for arbitrary selection. Thanks Seph.

Comment: This is a great trick, and should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @WoJ, Chrome 81 and still working, great.

Comment: @SAMPro: yes, it now works for me as well (also Chrome 81)

Comment: cool if you want to merge two or three windows, bit annoying if you want to merge e.g. 10 windows. Would be cool to merge multiple windows just by one mouse click. Anyway in simple scenarios your proposed solution is best as doesn't require to install any 3rd party addons.

Comment: Today (110.0.5481.100) it's even simpler, simply select all tabs with shift and then right-click and select Move to another window.

Comment: okay, but it only works within the same profile.
is there any method that can merge two Chrome windows of different profiles?

Comment: TIL. This is awesome

Answer (score 6):

I got confused by the steps provided, re-posting :

1. Left click first tab
2. Hold `shift` key or `ctrl` key
3. Left click and **hold** on another tab,  move tab(s) to another window

Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite extensions (certainly the one I use the most) is [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko).  It's so incredibly useful and merging windows is just one of it's many many features.

Comment: Hi Jay.  Nice extension although Kez answer was a better fit.  Thanks! Tal